# Short Story of Aliens Sailing/Mining on a Gas Giant who Attach to Females like Anglerfish

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

A couple years ago I read a short story set on/in a gas giant. The main character and narrator is an alien who flies a one man ship. He and the other males fly around and gather supplies and ultimately bring them back to the females. The females are giant flying whale/manta ray like creatures. If the males perform well, then they get to mate. This entails attaching to the stomach of a female and eventually getting absorbed like angler fish. The main character eventually finds a space craft (presumably human) and rescues it knowing it will give him the opportunity to mate. I can't find the story, and I would like to reread it.

Comment: Manta ray like aliens living in a gas giant remind me of the Dwellers from The Algebraist, but the plot does not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you're describing [The Deeps of the Sky](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/bear_06_18_reprint/) by Elizabeth Bear (link goes to the full story).

Elements which match your description:

- Main character is an alien who flies a one-man ship
- He's gathering resources for a large female ship he hopes to mate with
- He finds a human craft and makes contact
- At the end, he gets to merge with the large female ship

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining *why* you believe that.